# Why is recursive algorithm adding duplicate files?

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, task-parallel-library

Once I have all my C drive indexed for fast searching it helps a lot having multiple threads for searching for files! The only problem is that I am finding duplicate files. I will appreciate if someone could explain me why I am having duplicate files in the following algorithm.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static volatile List<System.IO.FileSystemInfo> files = new List<System.IO.FileSystemInfo> ( );
    static readonly object lockFiles = new object ( );  // every time we read or write to files we use this lock

    static long numberOfThreadsRuning; // used to determine when we are done. if 0 threads runing it means we are done!

    static readonly int max_Number_OF_Threads = 8; 

    static void Main (  )
    {
        numberOfThreadsRuning = 0;

        // add first task this will increase numberOfThreadsRuning
        AddTask ( () => findFiles ( @"C:\Users\Antonio" ) );

        // while number of threads running is greater than 0
        while ( Interlocked.Read ( ref numberOfThreadsRuning ) > 0 )   
            Thread.Sleep ( 100 );            
    }

    // start finding files in a new thread
    static void AddTask (Action task )
    {
        // increment numberOfThreadsRuning with a lock
        Interlocked.Increment ( ref numberOfThreadsRuning );

        Task.Factory.StartNew ( task ).ContinueWith ( x =>
        {
            // once we are done executing the task decrement number of threads runing
            Interlocked.Decrement ( ref numberOfThreadsRuning );
        });
    }

    // recursively start finding files
    static void findFiles ( string path )
    {
        System.IO.FileSystemInfo[ ] subDirAndFiles;

        try {
            subDirAndFiles = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo (path).GetFileSystemInfos ( );
        }
        catch { // sometimes we are not able to access some directories so just ignore the error
            return;
        }

        foreach ( var file in subDirAndFiles )
        {
            lock(lockFiles)
                files.Add ( file );

            if ( file is System.IO.DirectoryInfo ) // if it is a directory
            {
                var numTaskRun = Interlocked.Read (ref  numberOfThreadsRuning );

                if ( numTaskRun < max_Number_OF_Threads )
                    AddTask ( ( ) => findFiles ( file.FullName ) ); // if there are 8 or less threads running create a new task
                else
                    findFiles ( file.FullName ); // otherwise continue finding files in current thread
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

please try and compare how much faster it is when I use 8 threads VS 1 by changing the static variable `max_Number_OF_Threads` to `1`.  Another way to prove that my algorithm is wrong, it always finds a different number of files `(files.Length = different number)` every time I have more than 1 thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
foreach ( var file in subDirAndFiles )
{

    ...
    AddTask ( ( ) => findFiles ( file.FullName ) );
}
```

(Aside from the enormous number of spaces, which make it really hard to read for me... along with the unconventional method name.)

You're capturing the loop variable within the lambda expression. That means (in C# 3 and 4) the variable will be evaluated *when the lambda expression executes* - which means you may get the value from a later iteration.

The fix is to copy the value into a "new" variable inside the loop:

```
foreach (var file in subDirAndFiles)
{
    var copy = file;
    AddTask(() => FindFiles(copy.FullName));
}
```

This has been changed in the C# 5 compiler so that you don't need the "copy" variable - instead, it's as if `foreach` declares a new variable on each iteration, which is a much more natural approach.

Comment: Incorrect. Hawks WISH they had his eyes. Where do you think the Google Glasses team got their inspiration?  From Cyborg Skeet, of course!  Unless you were making a M*A*S*H joke... if so, nevermind. :)